# Angular value coming in as 0 for data uri image.

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use a data uri string in a json array for an image source. The value is coming in correctly however the source of the image is coming in as 0.

if I use a console.log to view my object and put the value into the inspector it works.

I've searched through the inter webs and can not for the life of me find any reason why angular would return a value of 0.

```
<img data-ng-src="{{category.bulb-off-image}}"/>
```

is my code

here is my data image :

```
data:image/jpeg;base64,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
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Wow you can't use dashes in variable names. I'll see myself out.

Comment: Yes, you can: category['bulb-off-image']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove the dashes of your variable name and everything should work perfectly.

The js parser would not be able to decide between a variable name and a subtraction operator inbetween two variable names.

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense. What a wild goose chase - Thank you Daniel.